# C# How to read and print date in switch

Tags: c#, date, while-loop, switch-statement

I want to put this date inside a switch statement that are inside a while loop. Don't know where to declare the variables to get it to work. I also want to allow the string date handle wrong input. How does that work on a string?

```
string date = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);            
Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
```

This is my code

```
while(true) {
   Console.WriteLine("[1] Enter date (dd/mm/yyyy)");
   Console.WriteLine("[2] Print date");
   Int32.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(), out answer);

   switch (answer) {
   case 1:
   break;
   }

   case 2:
   break;
   }    
}
```

Comment: To handle invalid dates it would be best to use `DateTime.TryParse`.

Comment: Sometimes it is best to buy a book and read it, rather then ask unfocused question.   Learning to program is hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a `DateTime` variable outside the loop and you can use `DateTime.TryParse` to determine if the date they entered is valid.  You could also use `DateTime.TryParseExact` if you only want to allow one date format for entry.  You could also allow for them to end the loop as well.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
bool keepGoing = true;
while (keepGoing)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[1] Enter date (dd/mm/yyyy)");
    Console.WriteLine("[2] Print date");
    Console.WriteLine("[3] Stop");
    int answer;
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer);

    switch (answer)
    {
        case 1:
            if(!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dt))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
            break;
        case 3:
            keepGoing = false;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Entry");
            break;
    }
}
```